# How to apply CSS on Unordered List written by JSP tag on web Page

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have a JSP custom Tag

```
<ex:UndorderdList list="<%= MenuItems%>"></ex:UndorderdList>
```

which finally creates unordered list and displays a tree using **jsTree**  on web Page.

In my Custom tag java file,I have:-

```
pageContext.getOut().write(htmlString);
```

here htmlString contains my unordered list.
I want to display an image in front of each of the items in my unordered list.

I create the tree using jsTree.js which renders the page once again. `$(document).ready(function() { $("#UndorderdList").jstree(); });`This is in `<head>` So,I think I should do something after this method call.But I don't know how should I do.:(

I need help/guidance.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google for "css li image", and you'll find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about JSP, but I am sure if you can attach a CSS file to your application and target, `<ul> and <li>`  on your styles, it should render the styles. As ultimately your code ends up in a browser. look at [here](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/vertical05.htm) on how to get an image as bullet for your `li`'s

Comment: It won't be possible that way cause I already tried it.I think i should give more info :)

I create the tree using jsTree.js which renders the page once again.
`$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#UndorderdList").jstree();

 });`This is in <head>
So,I think I should do something after this method call.But I don't know how should I do.:(

Answer (score 0):

the same way you'd do with plain HTML; by applying a CSS rule with `list-style-image` to the unordered list.

there are other ways (like granting the list items with pseudo elements, and apply a background image to them), but `list-style-image` is most widely supported.

**References:**

- [`list-style-image` on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/list-style-image)
- [CSS-Tricks reference on creating triangular bullets](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/triangular-list-bullets/) (can be used with images as well)
- [an article on MacWorld on custom bullets for lists](http://www.macworld.com/article/1048296/januarycreate.html)

Comment: most welcome. feel free to express your appreciation by ticking the "accepted" or up-voting the answer, thanks.

Comment: now i can't do up-voting..still 8 point..we need atleast 15...the moment i reach there..surely i will come back to thread n do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following import statement to import java.util.List:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
```

BTW, to import more than one class, use the following format:

```
<%@ page import="package1.myClass1,package2.myClass2,....,packageN.myClassN" %>
```

Comment: I don't understand that how importing my classes will display image..
I guess u misunderstood the question

Comment: this is import statement to import java util list

Comment: Yes I know..But this is not required in my context.